# Magento 2: argument type error on compilation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.8

I have compilation issue in my module. While I am running command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` facing this issue in magento 2.1.8. It's showing this error:

```
Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
```

Here is my file:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Mkt\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

/**
 * Fancyfeedbacktab fancyfeedback model
 */
class Orderapi extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel     
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */

    public $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $this->host=$this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_HOST_KEY, $storeScope);
        $this->clientId=$this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_CLIENT_ID, $storeScope);
        $this->clientSecret=$this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_SECRET_KEY, $storeScope);
        //parent::__construct($context, $registry, $ScopeInterface, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function -

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Collection as CreditmemoCollection;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Transaction\Collection as TransactionCollection;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Collection as ShipmentCollection;


class Orderapi extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var ProductMetadataInterface
     */
    protected $_appProductMetadataInterface;

    /**
     * @var Resource
     */
    protected $_modelResource;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_messageManagerInterface;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $_invoiceCollection;

    /**
     * @var ShipmentCollection
     */
    protected $_shipmentCollection;
    /**
     * @var CreditmemoCollection
     */
    protected $_creditmemoCollection;
    /**
     * @var TransactionCollection
     */
    protected $_transactionCollection;

    public function __construct(Context $context, 
        Registry $registry, 
        ProductMetadataInterface $appProductMetadataInterface, 
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $modelResource, 
        ManagerInterface $messageManagerInterface, 
        Collection $invoiceCollection, 
        ShipmentCollection $shipmentCollection, 
        CreditmemoCollection $creditmemoCollection,  
        TransactionCollection $transactionCollection, 
        AbstractResource $resource = null, 
        AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null, 
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_appProductMetadataInterface = $appProductMetadataInterface;
        $this->_modelResource = $modelResource;
        $this->_messageManagerInterface = $messageManagerInterface;
        $this->_invoiceCollection = $invoiceCollection;
        $this->_shipmentCollection = $shipmentCollection;
        $this->_creditmemoCollection = $creditmemoCollection;
        $this->_transactionCollection = $transactionCollection;

        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
```

Comment: `Incompatible argument type: Required type: array. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb` getting this error now

Comment: Are you using these 2 dependencies that you injected in constructor?

Comment: And delete var/generation folder and retry

Comment: I deleted `var/generation`. but its not working

Comment: I have updated the answer and this is a working Model

Comment: In your construct method,  I can see the parent::__construct() commented.. //parent::__construct($context, $registry, $ScopeInterface, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data); , please uncomment it, remove var/generation and check it again.